# Need additions to SUMIF Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm currently using the following formula to compute the sum of specific data within a sheet:

```
=SUM((SUMIF(D:D,{"90791","99343"},F:F)))
```

However, I am in search of an addition to this formula. I have a duration column (`F`) in which I have minutes from 1-250. I need this formula to never count more than 120 for each cell in column `F`. So if a cell in column `F` was 124, I would want the formula to treat it as 120 when summing.

Please let me know if you are aware of a formula that allows me to do all of these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use this array formula

```
=SUM(IF(((D1:D100=90791)+(D1:D100=99343))>0,IF(F1:F100>120,120,F1:F100)))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Also note that the references are no longer full column and should be set to the extents of the data set to avoid unnecessary calculations.

Comment: This formula gave me the wrong answer of 35. I have three cells in column F that this formula pertains to. There values are 118, 115, and 121. I need the formula to round down the 121 to 120 and then sum them. The correct formulated answer would give me 353. Thanks!

Comment: @B-Millionaire see edit

Comment: Scott, we appear to be getting closer, but the formula is summing all cells in column F instead of only the ones that have the code 90791 and 99343 in column D.

Comment: Scott, never mind. Your formula is accurate. I failed to follow instructions with control-alt-enter. Thank you so much for your assistance!

Comment: @B-Millionaire please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.